# fetch json data with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, express

So i have a simple api with express thats running on localhost:3000/api . It shows some json data

```
var express   = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
path       = require('path'),
scraperjs = require('scraperjs');

var app = express();

var crun = 'http://www.example.com/';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('http://www.example.com/link')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".h2 a").map(function() {
            return {
                title: $(this).text(),
                link: crun + $(this).attr('href')
            }
        }).get();
    }, function(news) {
        res.jsonp(news);
    })
})

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('alles oke');
```

And now i am trying to fetch it with angularjs. The angularjs app runs on port 1337 (if that matters) but i am getting the whoops error but i don't understand why

```
.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http) {
      var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
      $http({
          method: 'JSONP',
          url: url
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.news = data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('Whoops error');
      });
```

My error is `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/api' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

**FOUND FIX**

i used a module called cors for node and just added

```
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Did you try to open http://localhost:3000/api in a browser?

Comment: why is your $http({ method: 'JSONP') ? aren't you trying to use the GET method to fetch the data?

Comment: @Michelem yes and it works

Comment: So change `JSONP` to `GET` or change Node to `res.jsonp(news);`

Comment: @TheLazyChap when i change the method to GET i get an angularjs error and when i change it in JSON i get ` XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: @Joey what is the angular error? Can you kindly please add it to the original question, it might help others more if we know what is wrong?

Comment: @Michelem when i change the node to `res.jsonp(news);` i get `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/api' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: @TheLazyChap i changed the code in the original question

Comment: Change Node to `res.jsonp(news);` and change Angular from `JSONP` to `GET`

Comment: @Michelem i get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access.`